# MYSQL use GROUP BY to SUM timediff to get a total open time

Tags: mysql, time, group-by, sum

I have multiple tables that I am having to join together in order to work out how long tickets have been open, I am using the following query (convoluted I know!):

```
SELECT DISTINCT u_db.environments.name AS Env_name, TIMEDIFF(u_db.tickets.close_date, u_db.tickets.created_date) AS Total_open_time 
FROM u_db.tickets
INNER JOIN u_db.ticket_units
ON u_db.tickets.id = u_db.ticket_units.ticket_id
INNER JOIN u_db.units
ON u_db.ticket_units.unit_id = u_db.units.id
INNER JOIN u_db.locations
ON u_db.units.location_id = u_db.locations.id
INNER JOIN u_db.location_groups
ON u_db.locations.locations_group_id = u_db.location_groups.id
INNER JOIN u_db.environments
ON u_db.location_groups.environment = u_db.environments.id
WHERE u_db.tickets.created_date >= '2021-09-01 00:00:00'
AND u_db.tickets.created_date < '2021-10-01 00:00:00'
AND u_db.location_groups.id IN (50,17,46,45,48,49)
AND u_db.tickets.id IN (132357,132361,132372,132473);
```

Note: the close_date and created_date are stored as TIMESTAMP.

This generates the following output:

```
Env_name Total_open_time
GA       27:38:59
GA       01:43:51
GR       04:32:58
GR       49:39:19
```

However, I would like to group by Env_name and SUM the Total_open_times for each group, so my desired output is:

```
Env_name Total_open_time
GA       29:22:50
GR       54:12:17
```

I cannot seem to get the times to totals to sum when I group by Env_name, any suggestions on how to achieve this would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Guess you can sum with difference in seconds, then convert seconds to time

```
SELECT u_db.environments.name AS Env_name, SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, u_db.tickets.created_date, u_db.tickets.close_date))) AS Total_open_time 
FROM u_db.tickets
INNER JOIN u_db.ticket_units
ON u_db.tickets.id = u_db.ticket_units.ticket_id
INNER JOIN u_db.units
ON u_db.ticket_units.unit_id = u_db.units.id
INNER JOIN u_db.locations
ON u_db.units.location_id = u_db.locations.id
INNER JOIN u_db.location_groups
ON u_db.locations.locations_group_id = u_db.location_groups.id
INNER JOIN u_db.environments
ON u_db.location_groups.environment = u_db.environments.id
WHERE u_db.tickets.created_date >= '2021-09-01 00:00:00'
AND u_db.tickets.created_date < '2021-10-01 00:00:00'
AND u_db.location_groups.id IN (50,17,46,45,48,49)
AND u_db.tickets.id IN (132357,132361,132372,132473)
GROUP BY Env_name
```

Comment: Somehow this gives me the following result: GA 55:17:58 GR 63:18:13 which is not the correct answer unfortunately, any further ideas?

Comment: @Ikthezeus it has to be other reason, not related to `SEC_TO_TIME` & `TIMESTAMPDIFF`, they return same result as `TIMEDIFF`, refer to https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=6cdf4b43981f57ec2f97afbe706dcfc5 for a demo